# What's the difference between LocalMemoryManager and ClusterMemoryManager in Presto?

Tags: presto

I'm learning Presto. I've found two MemoryManager in Presto, LocalMemoryManager and ClusterMemoryManager. At frist I though they are different implementation depends on the Cluster's mode. But I found it's wrong.

The ClusterMemoryManager refer to the LocalMemoryManager's three MemoryPoolId. But I don't know the difference between them.

```
 private static final Set<MemoryPoolId> POOLS = ImmutableSet.of(GENERAL_POOL, RESERVED_POOL, SYSTEM_POOL);
```

I'v looked up some information but couldn't find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!